# Django model complex filter

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This are the model attributes:

```
    name, version, date_added, last_modified
```

I have a list like this:

```
    [(name1, version1), (name2, version2), (name3, version3)...]
```

I want to filter the model by (name, version) tuple. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you mean filter

Comment: For every tuple from the list I want the object from database.

Comment: Can you imagine a corresponding SQL query?

Comment: This is invalid sql code. At least for postgres and MS SQL.

Comment: select * from database d, list l where d.name = l.name and d.version = l.version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
from operator import or_
from django.db.models import Q

l = [(name1, version1), (name2, version2), (name3, version3)...]

data = YourModel.objects.filter(reduce(or_, Q(name=name, version=version)
                                            for name, version in l))
```

I think both `in` in sql and django orm are designed for single field.